# Not able to login in sitecore..?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.5

Hi all i'm creating application in ASP.NET MVC 5 i'm doing everything right even all thing executing fine, i'm able to view sample layout but when i'm login in Sitecore using password 'b' that it's not giving any error but not able to login

Please anyone suggest me how to figure out this issue:

Comment: Did you check the log files? Are there any errors listed?

Comment: You can also try to replace your bin folder by fresh sitecore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey just extract the sitecore zip file than create a mvc 5 blank project & paste all dll from sitecore package to mvc project bin & copy all folder of sitecore & paste in mvc project folder attach database & give connection string that done...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a brand new installation of Sitecore? If not, it's entirely possible that somebody may have changed the admin account password or disabled that account for security reasons.

If you are working locally, you should be able to reset the admin. You can see this post by John West on how to restore the admin user:

http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/11/Restoring-Administrative-Access-to-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx